# Must a person do Teshuvah on sins done by previous Gilgulim?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, sources-mekorot, repentance-teshuvah, reincarnation

I see that the Chayei Adam in [Shabbos and Yom Tov Klal 143](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.143?lang=bi), in his explanation for Vidui and ideas for sins to include on the list, has an interesting note for the sins beginning with Beis (translation and emphasis mine):

> אם בעל חס ושלום בעילה אסורה יאמר ״בעלתי בעילות אסורות.״ וכבר כתבתי שנכון לכל אדם לומר כן **שמא חטא בזה בגילגול אחר**.
>
> If, G-d forbid, one had illicit relations, he should say “I had illicit relations.” I have already written that it is proper for all people to say this, **for perhaps he sinned in this in a different incarnation**.

Are there any other Poskim who quote this idea, that one should do Teshuvah for sins one did in other Gilgulim?

Comment: I wonder whether he means merely "it's not _improper_" i.e. not a lie

Comment: @msh210 As often as he talks about Gilgulim, I can’t find where he “already [wrote]” this that I could compare.

Comment: IMHO If you are already a master of repenting for what you did in this gilgul...maybe you have some spare time to consider previous ones. :) Interestingly, my Chabad siddur, (I have seen other siddurim that have it as well.) by Krias Shma before sleeping, has a formula where we forgive everyone , even in a previous gilgul.

Comment: Isn't the entire concept of gilgulim that one is returning as an atonement for a previous incarnation?

Comment: As an aide, not very impressed with the "perhaps"  as a way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are others who have said this before the CA and after him. Of recent poskim/kabbalists [Ben Ish Chai](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Hayyim)  echoed as follows ([1st year, p. Ki Tisa](https://www.sefaria.org/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Ki_Tisa%2C_Introduction.2?with=all&lang=bi)):

> והנה הדבר הזה יפלא: משה בחיר ה' מה עון ומה חטאת יש בידו שהכניס עצמו בכללם באומרו לעוננו ולחטאתנו, ואולם הדבר מובן על פי מה שכתב רבינו האר"י ז"ל בשער הכונות דמלבד מה שנענש האדם על חטאיו, עוד נענש על חבירו מטעם ערבות שכל ישראל הם גוף אחד כלול מאברים רבים, ולכן תקנו אנשי כנסת הגדולה הוידוי בלשון רבים, ולא בלשון יחיד שאינו אומר אשמתי בגדתי וכו'... כתב בחסד לאלפים יש לומר כל פרטי הודוי אע"פ שאין בו מהדברים הנזכרים בודוי, מפני דכל ישראל גוף אחד הם וכולם ערבים זה לזה ובפרט אם היה בידו למחות ולא מיחה דנקרא על שמו, וכמו שכתבו רבותינו ז"ל בגמרא (שבת נד:) על פרתו של רבי אלעזר בן עזריה שהיתה יוצאת ברצועה שבין קרניה, שלא שלו היתה אלא של שכנתו והואיל ולא מיחה בה נקראת על שמו, **וגם עוד הוא עצמו צריך להתוודות על מה שחטא בגלגולים שעברו גם כן, ומי יודע מה עשה אפשר שעבר על כל דברים אלו, ולכן אומרים נוסח הודוי חטאנו אנחנו ואבותינו, כלומר גלגולים הקודמים שנקראים אבות לזה הגוף שהוא עוד עתה בו**